# What tools are commonly used to visualize meteorological and climatological data?

Tags: data-visualization

I am interested in visualizing [meteorological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meteorology) and [climatological](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climatology) data.

Here we are talking about 2D/[3D](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/3D_visualization) visualization for [weather and climate elements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weather_and_climate#Elements_of_weather_and_climate):

- [Temperature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Temperature)
- [Pressure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atmospheric_pressure)
- [Wind](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wind)

### Example

[image]

---

We have used some tools previously, such as:

- [GrADS](http://www.iges.org/grads/)
- [Surfer](http://www.goldensoftware.com/products/surfer) (commercial software)
- [GIS Meteo](http://mapmakers.ru/en/main/products/gis.aspx) (commercial software)

What another tools (preferably open source) would you suggest for that purpose nowadays?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I know you mentioned GrADS, but it was the tool I used mostly for development of weather products, a little more intuitive and resource friendly than IDV when I coded, and generally pretty good rate of development.  You mentioned Open Source... did you know there is an OpenGrADS (http://opengrads.org/)?  Most friends involved in weather product development use a combination of GrADS\OpenGrADS for much of their work.  But I agree it doesn't produce knock-your-socks-off graphics.

Another commonly used free program is Gempak, another Unidata product, which really seems to be becoming outdated in my personal opinion).
And then you can talk high end graphics, you're going to pay more.  http://moe.met.fsu.edu/~hrw22/movies/WIND_Katrina_2005-08-28_00Z.gif is a great video of Katrina that was produced by someone I knew using Amira.  According to Wikipedia, you're looking at
"*Cost: $4,000 USD + $800/year support (2009)... although now has much more ugly/complex pricing structure where each feature is priced separately (eg: Amira Mesh Option $360). I believe at NCMIR we pay ~$9000/year for five user-license.*"  Ouch!

Answer (score 1):

I don't have an open source tool, but if you can get access to a [Level-II data feed](http://mesonet-nexrad.agron.iastate.edu/level2/raw/) (Level-II is minimally post processed radar data), I and a meteorologist friend use [GR2Analyst](http://www.grlevelx.com/gr2analyst_2/).  I would assume you know enough about weather sources to be able to figure out how to set this up.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking for an open source (and free) tool that can do 2D and 3D, which also includes access to a wide variety of datasets (obs, model output, remote sensing - radar level 2 and 3, satellite, and more!), then you might want to check out the Unidata Integrated Data Viewer (IDV):

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/idv/

Source code available here:

https://github.com/Unidata/IDV

The interface is a bit complex, but we have some youtube screencasts to help people get up and going:

http://www.youtube.com/user/unidatanews/videos

If you'd like to see a video for a specific thing, we are taking requests :-) (email support-idv@unidata.ucar.edu). We do yearly training workshops as well, and those materials are available online here:

http://www.unidata.ucar.edu/software/idv/docs/workshop/

Cheers!

Sean

Answer (score 1):

[Panoply](http://www.giss.nasa.gov/tools/panoply/) is a multiplataform desktop option if data is available in formats such NetCDF, HDF or GRIB.

I extracted the following text from his site that describes some of the characteristics:

- Slice and plot geo-gridded latitude-longitude, latitude-vertical, longitude-vertical, or time-latitude arrays from larger multidimensional variables.
- Slice and plot "generic" 2D arrays from larger multidimensional variables.
- Slice 1D arrays from larger multidimensional variables and create line plots.
- Combine two geo-gridded arrays in one plot by differencing, summing or averaging.
- Plot lon-lat data on a global or regional map using any of over 100 map projections or make a zonal average line plot.
- Overlay continent outlines or masks on lon-lat map plots.
- Use any of numerous color tables for the scale colorbar, or apply your own custom ACT, CPT, or RGB color table.
- Save plots to disk GIF, JPEG, PNG or TIFF bitmap images or as PDF or PostScript graphics files.
- Export lon-lat map plots in KMZ format.
- Export animations as AVI or MOV video or as a collection of invididual frame images.
- Explore remote THREDDS and OpenDAP catalogs and open datasets served from them.

If you are interested in interactive visualization over web, there are some options such as:

- [ncWMS](http://www.resc.rdg.ac.uk/trac/ncWMS): an webmapping server that reads NetCDF data and publish it using Web Mapping Service standard.
- GeoServer: another webmapping server that has plugin to read NetCDF data.

Answer (score 0):

Vtk (visualization Toolkit) is a C++ open source 2D and 3D visualization library that I use to visualize radar data in 3D.